# Javascript Strings, HTML and Character Entities in Dojox Charting Labels

Tags: html, string, charts, label, dojo

I am trying to use HTML in dojox charting pie chart label string

```
text: 'hello<span class="custom">^_^</span>world'
```

Using the chrome inspector on the pie chart label string, the output is

```
<div>
  "hello"
  <span&nbsp;class="custom">^_^world</span&nbsp;class="custom">
</div>
```

So obviously the span tag is not working because for some reason,
it decided to unescape the space entity AND wrap the tag around "world" too.

This is very strange and unexpected behaviour, and I would like to hear from anyone who may know what is going on here.

Thanks,

aylz5073